# dijit/form/Select onSelect event

Tags: events, dojo

Are there other events that can be registered with dojo/form/Select, except onChange?

I'd need to execute a callback function every time user selects an option, even though he selects the same option as it was selected last time. The options I have tried: onSelect, onClick did not work.

```
        var spatialSelectionStore = new Memory({
        data: [
            { label: "Rectangle", id: "RECT" },
            { label: "Polygon", id: "POLY" },
            { label: "Circle", id: "CIRC" },
            { label: "Freehand", id: "FREE" }
        ]
    });

    var os = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: spatialSelectionStore });

    spatialQuerySelect = new Select({
        id: "selectionType",
        style: { width: "100px" },
        store: os,
        onChange: activateDrawTool
    }, "cp_selectByShapeId");
    spatialQuerySelect.startup();
```

Comment: `onChange` and `onClick` are really the best ways to go about this. Could you show us what you tried and why your attempts didn't work?

Comment: the above code works, but only for onChange event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this, and while it may not be the *best* way to do it, it seems to work.

I set up an aspect to fire a function after the `Select._setValueAttr` function executes, which is fired by the widget every time you click on either the menu drop-down or a drop-down item. Because of this, I added a check to make sure the function callback only fires when you click on a menu item (i.e. after the menu has closed). I also had to delete the `onChange` callback you added to `Select` manually, as this interfered with the aspect.

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
require(["dojo/aspect", "dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/Select", "dojo/data/ObjectStore", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/dom", "dojo/aspect"], function(aspect, Memory, Select, ObjectStore, domConstruct, dom, aspect) {

    var spatialSelectionStore = new Memory({
        data: [
            { label: "Rectangle", id: "RECT" },
            { label: "Polygon", id: "POLY" },
            { label: "Circle", id: "CIRC" },
            { label: "Freehand", id: "FREE" }
        ]
    });

    var os = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: spatialSelectionStore });

    spatialQuerySelect = new Select({
        id: "selectionType",
        style: { width: "100px" },
        store: os
    }, "cp_selectByShapeId");
    spatialQuerySelect.startup();

    aspect.after(spatialQuerySelect, "_setValueAttr", function() {
        if(spatialQuerySelect.dropDown.isShowingNow === false) {
            alert(spatialQuerySelect.get('value'));
        }
    });

    domConstruct.place(spatialQuerySelect.domNode, dom.byId("foo"), "first");
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nn3P3/)**

Aspects can be very powerful, but if you use too many and rely on them too heavily, you can end up with a *horrible* mess of spaghetti code, so I recommend you use them sparingly, and only when necessary.

In case you're not familiar with what they do, you can tell an aspect to fire `before`, `after`, or `around` another method, and the aspect will "listen" to that method being fired and behave appropriately with your function callback. [Further documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/aspect.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
spatialQuerySelect.dropDown.on("execute",function() {
alert(spatialQuerySelect.get('value'));
});
```

this would also work for all option.

```
onExecute: function(){
            // summary:
            //      Attach point for notification about when a menu item has been executed.
            //      This is an internal mechanism used for Menus to signal to their parent to
            //      close them, because they are about to execute the onClick handler.  In
            //      general developers should not attach to or override this method.
            // tags:
            //      protected
        },
```